# Flutter bloc bad state of stream

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

in my class `Repository()` I have two `streamcontrollers` running who are listening to changes.

```
  final remoteStreamController = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
  Stream<dynamic> get remoteId =>
      remoteStreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream();

  final localStreamController = StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();
  Stream<dynamic> get localJoined =>
      localStreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
```

now when there is an event in my app Im using `sink` to provide informations threw them, so my `bloc.dart` where im listening to stream changes can do some work in my app.

```
class GameBloc extends Bloc<GameBlocEvent, GameBlocState> {
  final Repository repository;
  VideocallBloc(this._agoraRepository) : super(VideocallInitial()) {
...
repository.localJoined.listen((res) {
      repository.lastLocal = res["localJoined"];
      repository.lastRemote = res["remoteId"];
      add(UpdateVideoCall(engine: res["engine"], joined: repository.lastLocal ?? false, remote: repository.lastRemote ?? -1));
    });

    repository.remoteId.listen((res) {
      repository.lastLocal = res["localJoined"];
      repository.lastRemote = res["remoteId"];
      add(UpdateVideoCall(engine: res["engine"], joined: repository.lastLocal ?? false, remote: repository.lastRemote ?? -1));
    });
```

when the bloc doesn't need the state anymore it calls the close() function, where im closing the streams and some other stuff from my app.

this is the part in my `bloc.dart`:

```
@override
  Future<void> close() async {
    //cancel streams
    await _repository.localStreamController.close();
    await _repository.remoteStreamController.close();

    await _repository.engine?.leaveChannel();
    await _repository.engine?.destroy();
    
    await super.close();
  }
```

If I need it again instead of creating the streams again, it throws me an error:

```
E/flutter ( 6080): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close
```

Actually, it wants to call `sink` in my `Repository()` again, but it doesn't find my two streams. How can I recall those streams again? I thought it does it automatically.

Comment: can you reproduce with the full code and where you are recalling the stream

Comment: This is pretty hard sondre the app is very big. Do you have a guess where I can search for?

Comment: oh okay but based on the code i will advice disposing stream as the bloc closes this is more advisable

Comment: Maybe you can share the repository link

Comment: you might consider assigning each stream to ```StreamSubscription``` and dispose them onclose of the bloc

Comment: Also in the repository class? Or in bloc? Could you provide me an example? Never worked with streamsubscription.

Comment: I edited my question with the close function of the bloc. this is called automatically if the bloc isnt needed anymore so it closes my streams and the engine. but when I again need the engine and the streams we have the error. i dont have the error on the engine, it will get initialized again in the Repository(), but my two streams arent

Comment: Back to your guess, actually I’m using streamsubscription in my bloc.dart. The events aren’t getting triggered anymore at this point because the sink.add in my repository isn’t called anymore because before the bloc.dart closed the streams automatically but didn’t recreate

Comment: that where this ```Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close``` is coming from because the bloc is already close and you are calling/updating the stream inside it so if you scope your bloc you can consider making it global or vice-versa

Comment: can i get repository link

Comment: there you go: I put every important file into the repository. if you need further informations or more files please tell me. https://github.com/md186/bloc_stream_error

Comment: okay i will update you

Comment: Morealso what i found is that you are closing the repository stream on bloc close

Comment: Im going to implement it as soon as I’m back home. Thank you very much for checking my code! If I write here, will you notice that? I’m case I have a question for better understanding

Comment: yes i will be available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider closing the stream with StreamSubscription instead of closing the repository stream directly as another bloc can be listening to the repository stream and it can cause a problem

```
class GameBloc extends Bloc<GameBlocEvent, GameBlocState> {
  final Repository repository;
  VideocallBloc(this._agoraRepository) : super(VideocallInitial()) {
localJoinedSubscription = repository.localJoined.listen((res) {
      repository.lastLocal = res["localJoined"];
      repository.lastRemote = res["remoteId"];
      add(UpdateVideoCall(engine: res["engine"], joined: repository.lastLocal ?? false, remote: repository.lastRemote ?? -1));
    });

  remoteIdSubscription = repository.remoteId.listen((res) {
      repository.lastLocal = res["localJoined"];
      repository.lastRemote = res["remoteId"];
      add(UpdateVideoCall(engine: res["engine"], joined: repository.lastLocal ?? false, remote: repository.lastRemote ?? -1));
    });
}

late final StreamSubscription localJoinedSubscription;
late final StreamSubscription remoteIdSubscription;

@override
  Future<void> close() async {
    //cancel streams
    //this just make sures the current bloc closes the stream you are listening to
    localJoinedSubscription.cancel();
    remoteIdSubscription.cancel();

//any other thing you want to close 
    
    await super.close();
  }


}
```

Comment: okay im back, trying your code. Im getting a The method 'close' isn't defined for the type 'StreamSubscription'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'close' error. I guess its cancel in this case?

Comment: oh sorry it should be ```.cancel()```